# CFTs and hyperbolic spaces

Tags: conformal-field-theory

- Is there a good way to explain why its natural to consider CFTs to be on hyperbolic spaces?
- Even if I forget about CFTs is there a good way to explain if there is a way that the hyperbolic space can be said to be scale-invariant?